# Reverse proxy location block

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vps

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy for my vps. I have a website that needs to call from apis, such as https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1. Right now on my website in the console, I get http://www.my_domain.com/api/fng/?limit=1 404 not found. I'm using angular, so in my service class, I have the url as /api/fng/?limit=1. The server block I have right now on my vps is

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name {{my_ip}};

location / {
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass https://api.alternative.me/;
    proxy_set_header Host api.alternative.me;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

When I have this however, if I got to www.my_domain.com/api, I hit the endpoint https://api.alternative.me.
How can I set it so that when my app sees any url that starts with http://www.my_domain.com/api/{rest of api} it will forward it as [https://api.alternative.me/{rest](https://api.alternative.me/%7Brest) of api}? Thanks.